# v-model keeps showing the same data in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i'm looping a form but the data for the first form keeps displaying in the second form
this is how my form is

```
    <div
      class="container"
      v-for="(passenger, passengerIndex) in passengers"
      :key="passengerIndex"
    >
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="firstName"
          v-model="passenger.FirstName"
        >
      </div>
```

this is my return

```
      passengers: [
        {
          FirstName: "",
        }
      ],
```

this is the behaviour anything i type for the form in first row it shows in the second row[image]

please how can i go about this

Comment: First name has to be an array. You have multiple first names.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vue 3 you can easily use `Ref` in your array in order to get this changes

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

interface Passenger {
  firstname: string
  lastname: string
}

// update v-model
const passengers = ref<Passenger[]>([
  {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
  }
])
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(passenger, passengerIndex) in passengers">
    <label>first name {{ passenger.firstname }}</label>
    <input v-model="passenger.firstname" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope this helps out